# Interactive Live Streaming in React native Agora SDK

Tags: react-native, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I'm trying to integrate Interactive live streaming in the React native app. It works fine with the temp token and console generated channel name, But in real-world example when the user goes for the live stream it will create its own channel so for this purpose, I use the NODEJS server to generate token with APP ID and APP CERTIFICATE and gets the token then I pass generated token JoinChannel.

- this.state.token = TOKEN GENERATED FROM SERVER
- this.state.channelName    = I USE USER ID TO AS CHANNEL NAME (this is
  the same name that I pass to the server while generating token)
- this.state.userId  = MONGO DB USER ID (this is the same id that I pass to the server while generating token)
- this.state.channelName = this.state.userId = 612e77c536d8140016ee4ef2

`await this._engine?.joinChannel(this.state.token, this.state.channelName, null, this.state.userid)`

After that, I got nothing in CONSOLE and  *JoinChannelSuccess* not fired.

Comment: What do you mean by the last bullet point? (this.state.channelName = this.state.userId = 612e77c536d8140016ee4ef2) It doesn't look right.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem with your credentials. A common error can be setting the expiry time too low when generating the token using NodeJS. Another common error can be mixing the userId type, you can choose between userAccount or integer type. I'd suggest double checking all the values in both places.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <RtcSurfaceView canvas={{ rtcUid: rtcUid }} style={styles.videoView/>
```

You need to change your `uid` to `rtcUid`.

Answer (score -1):

```
await this._engine?.joinChannel(this.state.token, this.state.channelName, null, parsInt(this.state.rtcUid))
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.